# log alert: unknown group "power" in message bus config file

Tags: log, groups

Server v18.04 log has many of these:

```
Sep  3 21:32:17 [pcname] dbus-daemon[1179]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

This comes from thermald.

short description

> Thermal Daemon is a Linux daemon for monitoring and
>    controlling platform temperatures. Once the system
>    temperature reaches a certain threshold, the Linux daemon
>    activates various cooling methods to try to cool the system.

```
dpkg -L thermald | grep dbus
/etc/dbus-1
/etc/dbus-1/system.d
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.thermald.conf
/usr/share/dbus-1
/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services
/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.thermald.service
```

and

```
   cat /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.thermald.conf
```

Forget to copy the part.

```
 <policy group="power">
                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.thermald"/>
                <allow receive_sender="org.freedesktop.thermald"/>
        </policy>
```

background

> This was the best suggestion I got to avoid
>   ThermalMonitor GUI running as a root to be able to send message to
>   thermald.

[source](https://github.com/intel/thermal_daemon/issues/162)

Comment: Well, I kinda understand.  Is this an error or do I just ignore it, maybe put it in the logcheck ignore list?

Comment: If you're running a VPS on some cloud service, you can just uninstall thermald.

Comment: It's not clear what the answer means.  In particular, what does "*Forget to copy the part.*" mean?  And it doesn't say why it would be wrong to make the obvious fix (create group "power").

Answer (score 2):

Tested on ubuntu 20.04 desktop machine:
Creating group `power` and adding user to `power` group stops error message on reboot.

`sudo groupadd power`
`sudo usermod --groups power --append $USER`

from `man thermald`:

thermald is a Linux daemon used to prevent the overheating of platforms. This daemon monitors temperature and applies compensation using available cooling methods.

By default, it monitors CPU temperature using available CPU digital temperature sensors and maintains CPU temperature under control, before HW takes aggressive correction action.

Other References:
https://01.org/linux-thermal-daemon/documentation/introduction-thermal-daemon
https://wiki.debian.org/thermald